# Is there a tool similar to microsoft system centre configuration manager available on in Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, fedora, linux-distributions

I am looking out for a tool similar to microsoft system centre configuration manager on linux platform which is available with GNU license and that can be used for doing multiple tasks like to automate the steps for deployment of operating systems(Fedora), steps after deployment of operating systems (Fedora),installation of application/packages on linux (fedora or Centos)...... and so on.

Comment: No, because I haven't written it yet.

Answer (score 0):

See [Anaconda](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda)

> Installation can be scripted with kickstart to provide a fully unattended installation that can be duplicated on scores of machines.

The [Kickstart web-page](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart) says

> Use the %packages command to begin a kickstart file section that lists the packages you would like to install

and

> You have the option of adding commands to run on the system once the installation is complete. This section must be at the end of the kickstart file and must start with the %post command. This section is useful for functions such as installing additional software and configuring an additional nameserver.